# Obtener datos de base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

He creado una sencilla base de datos con PhpMyAdmin, en ella almaceno 3 tablas:

1. Articulos
2. Autores
3. Tematicas

Quiero obtener los valores que están almacenados en la tabla `Temáticas`. He utilizado el siguiente código con PHP:

```
<?php
        $usuario = "root";
        $contrasena = "";
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $database = "conocetumente";

        //CREAMOS LA CONEXIÓN CON EL SERVIDOR QUE SE ALMACENARÁ EN $conexion
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena) or die("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor");

        //CREAMOS LA CONEXIÓN CON LA BASE DE DATOS QUE SE ALMACENARÁ EN $db
        $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database) or die("No se ha podido conectar con la base de datos");

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM TEMATICAS";

  $datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
  $arrayDatos = mysqli_fetch_array($datos);

  print_r ($arrayDatos);
?>
```

Al ejecutar el `print_r ($arrayDatos)` me muestra lo siguiente:

Array ( [0] => [id] => )

En dicha tabla tengo almacenado 3 valores, que son: `""` , `"esto es un tema"` y `"otro tema"`.
Si mal no entiendo, debería mostrarme dichos valores pero no lo hace. 
Es la primera vez que intento obtener datos de una base de datos, por lo que agradecería la mayor explicación posible.

Adjunto imagen sobre como está construida mi tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. No te van a mostrar esos datos porque estás haciendo select de los id. 2. Revisa si tienes la tabla en mayúsculas.

Comment: La tabla está creada en mayúsculas y el único campo que contiene la tabla es "id".

Comment: Pero el select lo tienes con minúsculas el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: Lo que tengo en minúsculas es el nombre del campo, el nombre de la tabla está en mayusculas. No obstante, he probado todas las combinaciones posibles de mayúsculas y minúsculas y sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado

Comment: @Alexander para la cuestión de los dos índices, revisa mi respuesta editada (*in fine*). Debes usar un método específico, porque `fetch_array` te indexa los datos dos veces por su definición.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es muy simple: cuando consulta a la base de datos lo que obtienes es un puntero hacia los datos. Luego tienes que aplicar alguno de los métodos `fetch` para obtener cada fila.

Al aplicar `fetch` una sola vez, obtienes únicamente la primera fila (el `print_r` aparece en blanco porque en esa primera fila además no tienes datos según muestra la imagen). Pero **no hay más filas, porque no mueves más el puntero**.

Esto se resuelve generalmente moviendo el puntero dentro de un bucle (generalmente `while`).

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
        $usuario = "root";
        $contrasena = "";
        $servidor = "localhost";
        $database = "conocetumente";

        //CREAMOS LA CONEXIÓN CON EL SERVIDOR QUE SE ALMACENARÁ EN $conexion
        $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contrasena, $database) or die("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor");

  $sql = "SELECT id FROM TEMATICAS";

  $datos = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
  $arrayDatos = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
    $arrayDatos[] = $row;
  }
  print_r ($arrayDatos);
?>
```

La clave de todo está aquí:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
```

Lo que hacemos ahí es mover el puntero de datos, aplicándole `mysqli_fetch_array` en cada iteracción, así nos va a traer en `$row` cada fila, luego, dentro del bucle, metemos cada fila dentro de `$arrayDatos`.

He hecho una pequeña mejora en ut código. Con `mysqli` puedes seleccionar la base de datos al momento de conectar, pasándola como cuarto parámetro a la función de conexión.

### Elegir el método `fetch` adecuado

Debes tener en cuenta que `mysqli_fetch_array` te va a indexar los datos dos veces: como array asociativo y como array numérico (a no ser que hagas una configuración previa de la API, pero no vale la pena).

`mysqli` tiene el método [`fetch_row`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) numérico, en ese caso el código sería así:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($datos)){
    $arrayDatos[] = $row;
  }
```

Y tiene el método [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) para array asociativo, en cuyo caso, el código sería así:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)){
    $arrayDatos[] = $row;
  }
```

Deberías usar el método específico según el tipo de datos que quieras.

Cabe decir también que [`fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) puede recibir en parámetro el tipo de resultado que quieres, mediante dos constantes definidas: `MYSQLI_NUM` para array numérico y `MYSQLI_ASSOC` para array asociativo.

En ese caso el código sería así:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos, MYSQLI_NUM)){ 
    //...
}
```

O así, según el caso:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    //...
}
```

Pero esto se hace demasiado verboso, es mejor usar los métodos directos. Y, como recomendación, es mejor que implementes el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es menos verboso, más claro y más moderno.

Está todo explicado en el Manual de PHP (ver enlaces de los diferentes métodos).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu aportación tan bien fundamentada, da gusto recibir ayuda de esa manera tan volcada.

Answer (score 1):

---EDIT---

Te falta iterar (pasar de uno en uno) el resultado de la función `mysqli_fetch_array($datos)`, se realiza de la siguiente manera:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){
    $arrayDatos[] = $row;
}
```

`$row` sirve como una variable auxiliar que va almacenando cada fila que te regresó tu consulta, en el primer ciclo del `while` la variable `$row` almacena el primer resultado (en tu caso un vacío), después al usar `$arrayDatos[] = $row` almacenas en tu variable "final" el primer resultado, los caracteres `[]` indican que se va a guardar en el siguiente indice del arreglo y así no tienes que poner el numero del indice del arreglo, siempre toma el siguiente. Así en todos los ciclos hasta que la condición del while no se cumple, que es cuando ya no hay mas registros que obtener. al final tu variable `$arrayDatos` está llena con todos los registros obtenidos y no solo con el primero como te pasaba.

Espero resolver tus dudas. Saludos.

Comment: Efectivamente, en mi tabla tengo un único campo llamado `id`. He probado con lo que me comentas y me sigue mostrando el mismo resultado.

Comment: Creo saber que pasa, en realidad si te está mostrando el resultado, te muestra el campo vacío, osea el primer resultado. intenta poner lo siguiente 

`while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($datos)){

   $arrayDatos[] = $row;
}`

y luego imprimes.

Esto hace que recorras todo lo que te regresa la función y la guardes en una variable.

Comment: Efectivamente, esa era la solución, podrías explicarme qué es `$row` exactamente??

Comment: Ok. Edito la respuesta y te lo explico ahí.

Comment: He obtenido el resultado esperado en cierta medida, al mostrar `$row` me muestra un array contiene, dentro de sí mismo, un array para cada valor de la tabla. Te lo muestro:

Comment: ` Array ( [0] => [id] => ) Array ( [0] => esto es un tema [id] => esto es un tema ) Array ( [0] => otro tema [id] => otro tema ) `

Comment: Entonces, por qué existen 2 índices??

Comment: A ok. eso pasa por que la función fetch que utilizas puede recibir un parametro opcional, en el cual decides que tipo de indice quieres, el indice numérico, o el indice asociativo, por defecto te trae los 2. pásate por la documentación de PHP para que veas mejor explicado y con ejemplos. te dejo el enlace. https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Answer (score 1):

En base a la consulta que estas indicando `$sql = "SELECT id FROM TEMATICAS";` solo le estas indicando que te traiga el id de la tabla temáticas, para extraer los valores que tengas almacenados suponiendo que tengas mas que solo los que mencionas entonces la construcción de tu select debería ser un poquito mas complejo, como no conozco la forma en que esta construida tu tabla, solo te pondré un ejemplo asumiendo que los campos se llaman de cierta manera.  La construcción mas sencilla del select seria así:`$sql = "SELECT ACTIVO , SUBACTIVO , DENOMINACION FROM bienes WHERE  NUMERO_EMPLEADO = 1`

y esto me regresa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo sustituye los datos que correspondan a tu tabla y obtendrás los resultados que requieres.  Te sugiero que te apoyes en software adicional yo tengo adicional al Phpmyadmin un programa que se llama Mysql Query Browser es muy practico de usar.

Comment: Entiendo tu aportación Cesarín, pero sigue sin funcionarme. He editado mi pregunta aportando una imagen de la tabla, quizás sea de ayuda

Comment: Si era lo que suponía que tienes solo un campo en tu tabla en base a tus comentarios, tal cual así como la tienes no te va a ser de mucha utilidad, al menos deberías tener dos campos uno con el id y el otro campo con el valor relacionado a ese id, y tu tabla la podrias rellenar asi id (1,2,3) y un campo relacionado con estos valores (HUGO , PACO , LUIS) asi si buscas por el 1, te dara HUGO, y asi sucesivamente...