# Fallo al insertar datos de una BBDD en una matriz

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy recorriendo un array, que tiene unos IdPedido de una tabla. He creado una matriz nueva para a partir de los IdPedido, sacar todos los campos de los registros que corresponden a dicho IdPedido de la BBDD MySQL y meter todos los campos en dicha matriz.

```
    $dataToInsertInMS=array();

    foreach($DBchanges as $idPedido){

        $queryWSidPedido= "SELECT Marketplace, IdPedido, fecha, nombre cliente, direccion, DNI, cp, poblacion, provincia, telefono FROM pedidos WHERE ".$idPedido;

        array_push($dataToInsertInMS[], $queryWSidPedido);

    }

    var_dump($dataToInsertInMS);
```

Hago el array push de todos los campos y luego uso el var_dump para ver que se está guardando bien en dicha matriz la operación. Sin embargo, me da los siguientes errores:  Array to string conversion, array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given. No sé por qué se producen. Muchas gracias.

Comment: `$queryWSidPedido` es la cadena que representa a la consulta. Para obtener los datos tienes que ejecutar esa consulta precisamente (con `mysqli_query()` eventualmente) y luego usar un método de lectura de los datos (uno de los métodos `fetch`) para llenar el array.

Comment: Con método de lectura de datos te refieres por ejemplo a un mysqli_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: Correcto. Y si esperas varias filas conviene hacer la lectura dentro de un `while`. En cuando al array, es más óptimo llenarlo así: `dataToInsertInMS[] = $row;` que usar `array_push()`. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335161/29967) en el contexto del `while` y se explica también cómo funciona la cuestión de las consultas y la lectura de datos, la diferencia entre los métodos, etc.