# mysqli_fetch_array solo devuelve el primer indice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Buenas a todos soy nuevo en php, tengo un problema con mysqli_fetch_array() y es que quiero hacer una consulta a una base de datos y que me devuelva todos los valores de una columna llamada ID_CONTACTO que tengan un id = 12, el caso es que por alguna razón solo me esta devolviendo el primer valor, tengo dos valores que cumplen los requisitos , pero solo parece que encuentra el primero, no creo que el problema esté en la consulta, ya que en phpMyAdmin la hice y me devuelve todos los valores, sin embargo en php no parece funcionar esto es lo que tengo, el problema estoy seguro que es una tontería, por lo que no subí más código, igual con eso debe de ser suficiente, todo me funciona bien menos eso.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT ID_CONTACTO FROM contactos WHERE id = 
'12'");
$numero = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
```

si pongo "$numero[0]" me devuelve "13", como cabría esperar, sin embargo "$numero[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xGiT.png)", pensé que me devolvería el otro valor, o sea "14", pero no me devuelve nada

[image: Esta es la tabla]

Comment: Realiza un `var_dump` de `$numero` y agrega que salida obtienes

Comment: Es un problema del método: "Si dos o más columnas del resultado tienen el mismo nombre de campo, la última columna tomará precedencia y sobrescribirá la información anterior. Para acceder a múltiples columnas con el mismo nombre, hay que usar la versión numéricamente indexada de la fila."  Link: https://manuales.guebs.com/php/mysqli-result.fetch-array.html

Comment: Probablemente sea porque en tu consulta estas comparando contra un string id = 
'12'"); intenta con id =12"); sin las comillas

Comment: Me sale esto:    " array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "13" [ID_CONTACTO]=> string(2) "13" } "

Comment: gracias a todos por responde, estuve buscando y no doy con con que es "versión numéricamente indexada de la fila", un problema que pensé que sería una bobería

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Obtener datos de base de datos con PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335133/obtener-datos-de-base-de-datos-con-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema ha sido tratado varias aquí ([ver por ejemplo esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/335161/29967)). Lo que ocurre es que `mysqli_query()` devuelve un recurso con los datos y al usar cualquiera de los métodos `fetch` (excepto `fetchall` que trae todos los datos de golpe, pero que sólo existe cuando tienes instalado el controlador `mysqlnd`) los datos se van obteniendo **fila por fila**.

Por eso en tu caso obtienes solamente un resultado, **porque aplicas una sola vez el método `mysqli_fetch_array()`**. Para obtener todas las filas, tienes que aplicar por cada una el método, y esto se hace por lo general usando un bucle `while`, como puedes ver en los ejemplos de la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php).

Por tanto, tu problema debería resolverse de este modo:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT ID_CONTACTO FROM contactos WHERE id = 
'12'");
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta) ) {
    echo $row[0].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Si no te interesa mostrar los datos in situ, puedes guardarlos en una variable para usarlos a posteriori:

```
$mData=array();

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) ) {
    $mData[]=$row;
}
#Usar o retornar $mData
```

Observa que aquí **he usado un método más específico**, porque `mysqli_fetch_array` te devuelve los resultados organizados al mismo tiempo como array asociativo y numérico, con una sola forma de organización sería suficiente.

Y, si te interesa imprimir con la forma asociativa, sería así:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) ) {
    echo $row['ID_CONTACTO'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Graciassss me acabo de probar la primera y me funciona okok, había leído lo del array, y tenia sentido, pero no sabía cómo ponerlo en práctica, ahora veo que es sencillo, estaba pasando trabajo para instalar mysqlnd,

Answer (score 0):

No se porqué da este error, pero lo acabo de intentar y me da el mismo error a mi tambien, quizas sea por la version de php, yo estoy usando la version 7.4.20 pero voy a seguir investigando a ver porque succede eso.

La forma que obtuve todos los resultados es usando la funcion `mysqli_fetch_all()` en vez de `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Asi:

```
consulta = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT ID_CONTACTO FROM contactos WHERE id = '12'");

// Ojo: como estas seleccionando varias filas,  devuelve un arreglo multidimensional
 $numero = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta);

// si quieres imprimir el 13 seria   echo $numero[0][0]   
// si quieres imprimir el 14 seria   echo $numero[1][0] 
// y asi sucessivamente (si tienes mas filas)
```

o bien podrias seleccionar las filas como un arreglo asociativo asi:

```
$numero = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// si quieres imprimir el 13 seria   echo $numero[0]["ID_CONTACTO"]   
// si quieres imprimir el 14 seria   echo $numero[1]["ID_CONTACTO"]
```

Si vas a trabajar mucho con base de datos te recomiendo que uses PDO O MySQLi(Orientado a Objetos) en vez de pleno mysqli.

Comment: no me funciona mysqli_fetch_all, estuve googleando y parece que tengo que instalar alguna extensión por ahí, gracias por tu respuesta, estoy considerando PDO o MySQLi